# How to allow users to create users using Django

Tags: python, django

I'm Working on a small CRM Project, using Django / Rest Framework.
I would like to create sub-users options for example a user can create some sub-accounts for the employes  for example

I don't know what should I do, or from where to start to make it

Comment: Look at django permissions

Answer (score 1):

Yes for that you can create staff_member this field is present in admin

Comment: can someone clarify more, i'm not looking for permissions, i'm looking for creating sub accounts :)    is that the same  idea ?

Comment: create form and save